# Angularjs ng-repeat columns responsive

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, responsive

i have an ng-repeat divided into max 2 columns in large devices. In this elements there's a button. When clicked the element can "exapands" and take the whole width of the page. The problem is that is i open one of the element on the right side, this one go down under the element on its left. The right behavior is when i open the elements on the left side. To be more precise, the elements under the one expanded should line correctly always in 2 columns. This is my example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/DR3wsVqkW3b4ZYaFUAZz?p=preview

Part of the code:

```
<div>
      <div class="row">
        <div ng-repeat-start="product in obj.products" class="clearfix" ng-if="$index % 2 == 0"></div>
        <div ng-repeat-end class="col-md-0 col-sd-6 col-lg-6 bg-danger" data-ng-class="{'openDiv': product.openIs == true}" style="cursor: pointer, z-index: 1">
          <h2>af {{product.title}}</h2>
          <div>
            <button ng-click="obj.doSomething(product)">Click to open</button>
          </div>
          <div ng-if="product.openIs == true">
              <p>This is inside</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
<style>
      .openDiv {
        width:100%!important;
      }
    </style>
```

and js:

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.obj = {
     products: [
      { title: 'text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 1' },
      { title: 'text text text2' },
      { title: 'text text text text text1' },
      { title: 'text text text2' },
      { title: 'text 1' },
      { title: 'text te text text text text text text text text text text xt2' },
      { title: 'text 1' },
      { title: 'text 2' },
      { title: 'text  text text text1' },
      { title: 'text 2' },
      { title: 'text text text textv text text text1' },
      { title: 'text 2' }
    ],

    openIs: false,
    doSomething: function(obj) {
       obj.openIs =! obj.openIs;
    }
  }

});
```

Hope someone can help me. Thanks

EDIT: To be more clear:

This is the case with all elements closed:
[image]

Here's when i expand one on the left column. As you can see it creates a empty space below (that's one problem)

[image]

Here's when i open one on the right column: same problem:

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: What is unclear? I can put in some screenshot maybe. Anyway, in simple words, it seems that it creates some empty space when i expand the element. Did you see the sample i post yesterday?

Comment: To see the 2 columns you need to expand the window on the right side. In medium/small screens you'll see only one column

Comment: @AliGajani check my edit

Comment: This is strictly a style issue. You're rendering DIVs, which are blocks. Their layout is governed by this. To change it you'll have to override their display property or change the type of elements you're rendering, or both. See http://learnlayout.com/display.html or Google "HTML style display".